# How to obtain data from Json in android?

Tags: android, json, get

In my app I need to obtain some data from server. In eclipse I receive data like this :

`[{"id_category":"1","category_name":"Cool"},{"id_category":"2","category_name":"Glamor"},{"id_category":"3","category_name":"Funky"},{"id_category":"4","category_name":"Crazy"},{"id_category":"5","category_name":"David Guetta"}]` without any name.

I tried something like this :

```
if (response != null) {
                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                System.out
                        .println("Rezultat de la server pentru a afla categoriile:"
                                + responseBody);
try {
                    final String r = response.toString();
String name = json.getString("category name");
System.out.println("One category"+name);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // do nothing
                } catch (FacebookError e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }
```

but nothing happens. How can I get `id_category` and `category_name` from my response?
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you parse JSON...I hope it works.

```
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(r);
    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject jsdata = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String myString = jsdata.getString("id_category");
            String myString2 = jsdata.getString("category_name");
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens and I don't understand why. I put JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(r);
     System.out.println("lung "+jArray.length());
     for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
             JSONObject jsdata = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
             String myString = jsdata.getString("id_category");
             String myString2 = jsdata.getString("category_name");
             System.out.println("Category name"+myString2);
     }
      but I can not see nothing in DDMS

Comment: Are you sure that JSON string looks like you've shown? What's the length of JSON Array?

Comment: I found the solution String r = responseBody.toString();

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski it was `String r = response.toString();` not `String r = responseBody.toString();` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Google Gson https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

It available for maven